# Login Redirect In magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.1.0 and i am trying to redirect customer to account edit page after login  instead of home page of dashboard after login

For this i created one plugin for login post and define that plugin in di.xml

Plugin Code:

```
<?php

namespace xxxx\xxxx\Plugin;

 class LoginPost
 {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $url;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
)
{
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
    $resultRedirect
) {
    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/edit'));
    return $resultRedirect;
}
 }
```

What i am doing wrong or miss something???

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either for a long amount of time. Have you tried enabling the `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` setting in admin panel under Stores -> Configurations -> Customers -> Customer Configuration? The observer seems to work for me from then on

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following Code?

```
protected $resultRedirectFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
    }
    public function afterExecute($subject, $result)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/edit');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

Comment: no, its also not working